# C++ in Arduino create instances of class

Tags: c++, arduino

How to create several instances of a class?

I want to have several classes, all like an interface in C# working with same structure but have different instances.

If I start the following construct, it tells me error, the class has no instanced "KEY".

I am using the struct `StateController` but it is just to show the environment, the issue already is in `String Key`.

**Base.h**

```
    #ifndef _BASE_H
#define _BASE_H
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "StateController.h"

class _Base
{
public:
    _Base();
    void Init(StateController *stateController);
    void Update(StateController *stateController);

private:
    String Key;
};

extern _Base _BaseInstance;
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
void setup()
{
// Here I can only access the _BaseInstance. 
// If I create a h file for each Class1.h/Class2.h/Class3.h I can access
// But throws exception because "Key" has multiple definitions.
  Class1.Init(&stateController);
  Class2.Init(&stateController);
  Class3.Init(&stateController);
}
```

**_Base.cpp**

```
#include "StateController.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "_Base.h"

//
//
//


StateItem stateItem;

_Base::_Base()
{
    Key = "Class 1";
}

void _Base::Init(StateController *stateController)
{
    stateItem = stateController->Add(Key);
}

void _Base::Update(StateController *stateController)
{
}
```

(questions updated with details)

Comment: why would you name objects "Class"? _instance_ of a _class_ is an _object_ in OOP

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's going on, since you haven't shared the code in Class1.h, Class2.h, and Class3.h, nor have you shown us where Class1, Class2, and Class3 are declared. Are these three objects instances of classes that are, themselves, inherited from _Base? Or are they just instances of _Base? Do you need polymorphism, or is it sufficient to use just the _Base class?

It sounds like you may be conflating a need for polymorphism with a need for different instances of the same class, and your code may reflect this.

Would it be sufficient to change your constructor to take a single String argument, which is then assigned to Key? You could do something like:

**Base.h**

```
#ifndef _BASE_H
#define _BASE_H
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "StateController.h"

class _Base
{
public:
    _Base(String _Key);
    void Init(StateController *stateController);
    void Update(StateController *stateController);

private:
    String Key;
};

extern _Base _BaseInstance;
#endif
```

Then define the constructor as:

**Base.cpp**

```
_Base::_Base(String _Key) :
    Key(_Key) {}
```

Then initialize individual objects accordingly:

**main.cpp**

```
_Base Class1 ("Class 1");
_Base Class2 ("Class 2");
_Base Class3 ("Class 3");

void setup()
{
  Class1.Init(&stateController);
  Class2.Init(&stateController);
  Class3.Init(&stateController);
}
```

Comment: Its sometimes very difficult to find the best way for compact asking and posting only relevant parts. In that case I will learn, I need to share more details. Thank you for your answer, I will try to understand and update my question.

Comment: My problem is in your line `_Base::_Base(String _Key) :`. I dont want to set the Key as string in constructor if possible, I want to setup it in cpp file. For example Class1. But then I have compiler issues as described. Am I wrong or am I not sharing enough details?

Comment: Why? I fail to see the purpose of this. Are all of your objects instantiations of different classes that inherit from the _Base class? If so, why? Can you share the code that declares and defines, for example, Class1?